# getting DateTime from ResultSet in JdbcTemplate

Tags: java, datetime, jdbc, jodatime, jdbctemplate

in database my column is of type TIMESTAMP, so my class has properties of type Datetime like this:

```
public void setDiscoveryDate(final DateTime discoveryDtTm) {
        this.discoveryDtTm = discoveryDtTm;
    }
```

now in JdbcTemplate I want to get it, so some code like this:

```
variant.setDiscoveryDate(rs.getTimestamp("discovery_dt_tm"));
```

which does Not work because column the get for resultset I could not find something that returns DateTime, I only saw either getDate or getTime.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That's because `DateTime` is not a standard Java type. If you're referring to the JodaTime type, then try this:

```
variant.setDiscoveryDate(
   new DateTime(rs.getTimestamp("discovery_dt_tm").getTime())
);
```

This will break if `rs.getTimestamp` returns `null`, so you may want to break this up into smaller statements and add checks for `null`.

Note that this can be made easier, since `DateTime`'s constructor takes a `java.util.Date`, which `Timestamp` is a subclass of:

```
variant.setDiscoveryDate(
   new DateTime(rs.getTimestamp("discovery_dt_tm"))
);
```

But it's also wrong, due to bad design of the `Timestamp` class (see [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) for explanation).

Stick with the first example (with `getTime()`)

Comment: thanks, so we are still getting only the tie with .getTime() and passing it to new DateTime , then what happends to Date?

Comment: @BDotA: `Timestamp.getTime()` is badly named - it returns the milliseconds since 1 Jan 1970, and so includes both date and time parts.

Comment: rs.getTimestamp() will return the raw value from the database, but *in the time zone of the JVM*. If you store UTC values in the database, new DateTime(rs.getTimestamp()) will return incorrect values - offset by whatever the UTC offset is.

Comment: This works great for me in my Spring MVC application that uses ResultSet and implements `RowMapper`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
variant.setDiscoveryDate(new DateTime(rs.getTimestamp("discovery_dt_tm").getTime()));
```